# How to update users information? woocommerce/wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Trying to update users information in a form for wordpress and woocommerce, however I click on "UPDATE INFO" and use jQuery to enable form then enter new user information, and on submit the form should fire the woocommerce_save_account_details function below, but it does nothing.
Please could someone help thanks.

```
<div class="info-wrapper"><!-- info-wrapper -->
    <label for="fname">FIRST NAME</label>
    <input id="firstName" class="info-input required" name="account_first_name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_first_name', $current_user->ID );?>" type="text" disabled="disabled">

    <label for="lname">LAST NAME</label>

    <input id="lastName" class="info-input required" name="account_last_name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_last_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" type="text" disabled="disabled">
    <label for="company">COMPANY / SCHOOL NAME</label>
    <input id="account_company" class="info-input required" name="account_company" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_company', $current_user->ID ); ?>" type="text" disabled="disabled">

    <label for="phone">PHONE NUMBER</label>
    <input id="phone" name="account_phone" class="info-input required" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_phone', $current_user->ID ); ?>" type="number" disabled="disabled">

    <label for="email">EMAIL (CONTACT US TO UPDATE YOUR EMAIL)</label>
    <input id="email" name="account_email" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" type="text" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="hidden" name="account_email" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'billing_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />


    <div class="submit-logout">
        <!-- update and logout button-->
        <div class="button-style1" id="update-button">UPDATE INFO</div>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="woocommerce_save_account_details" />
        <input type="submit" name="save_account_details" class="update_user submit-mess button-style1" id="update_user" value="save">

        <div class="logout_btn"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">LOGOUT</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="changePassword" href="#">Change Password</div>
</div><!-- info-wrapper end -->
```

-----------Functions.php file ---------

```
function wooc_save_extra_account_details($customer_id) {

   if ( isset( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) ) {
       // WordPress default first name field.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) );
       //mailchimp first name

       // WooCommerce billing first name.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) );
   }

   if ( isset( $_POST['account_last_name'] ) ) {
       // WordPress default last name field.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_last_name'] ) );

       // WooCommerce billing last name.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_last_name'] ) );
       //Mailchimp Lastname
   }

   if ( isset( $_POST['account_company'] ) ) {
       // WooCommerce company or school
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_company'] ) );

       // WooCommerce billing last name.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_company'] ) );
       //Mailchimp Lastname
   }

   if ( isset( $_POST['account_phone'] ) ) {
       // WooCommerce company or school
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_phone'] ) );

       // WooCommerce billing last name.
       update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_phone'] ) );


   }

   if ( isset( $_POST['account_email'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company or school
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'email', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_email'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing last name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_email', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_email'] ) );

    } 
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_address'] ) ) {
          // WooCommerce company or school
          update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing address', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address'] ) );

          // WooCommerce billing last name.
          update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_address_1', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_address'] ) );

    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['shipping_address'] ) ) {
         // WooCommerce company or school
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'shipping address', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['shipping_address'] ) );

         // WooCommerce billing last name.
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'shipping_address_1', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['shipping_address'] ) );

    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'wooc_save_extra_account_details' );
```

Comment: Can you add your jQuery code to your question?

Comment: My jQuery is only to enable and disable the Attribute                                                                    $('#update-button').click(function(){
    $(".info-input").removeAttr('disabled', false);
   $('#update-button').hide();
   $('.update_user').show();
   });

  // info change button
  $('.update_user').click(function(){
   $(".info-input").attr('disabled', true);
    $('.update_user').hide();

   $('#update-button').show();

     });

Comment: Alright, thought you're trying to fire the form by jQuery, my bad lol... So is the page you are firing the form a custom page, or it is the WooCommerce My Account page?... hows your <form> tag looks like?

Comment: it's the woocommerce my account page that I have customized a little. <form id="rego-form" action="" method="post">

Comment: I believe that the fuction maybe one drom class-wc-form-handler.php under save_account_details() so Im using this function to save users information. sorry but Im new at this lol thanks

Comment: Weird, I get your code and its working for me... When you debug the code, is all the info showing? like `function wooc_save_extra_account_details($customer_id) { var_dump($_POST); die(); //rest of the code... }`